# T.into() vs Some(x) are there any detriments of using .into()?

Tags: rust, type-constructor, option-type

I just observed for the first time that I could create Options with `.into()` instead of wrapping in `Some()`. Are there any downsides to this approach?

Comment: You'd need to supply a specific type annotation every time you use `.into()`, so why bother when you can just wrap it in `Some`? Not to mention that `Some` is much clearer. But yes, [the implementation just wraps it in `Some`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#1665-1678).

Comment: @Aplet123 in the case of the struct I'm loading the fields are already typed to `Option<String>`

Answer (score 2):

Codegen wise, there wouldn't be any downsides as the `.into()` just wraps the value in `Some()` too. The only problem might be if LLVM wasn't inlining the call.

In the code readability side though, `.into()` is far less clear than `Some()`. `.into()` is highly generic. That means, you could end up having to add type annotations, which is more effort than just wrapping yourself. Even in the cases where you don't need to add annotations, it can become difficult for the reader what the type of the expression is.

IMO, `.into()` should be used where the exact type is not important and is only an implementation detail. The meaning of the type should not change. Going from `Foo::Color` to `Foo::BetterForInternalUseColor` is an implementation detail and does not change meaning. Going from `T` to `Option<T>` does.

Comment: I don't disagree with your final para, but it does also rather suggest that `impl<T> From<T> for Option<T>` shouldn't exist.

Comment: As a general guideline, I prefer having too many trait implementations than not enough. Because of the orphan rule, it is better to have a trait implementation and not need it (maybe hide it behind a feature flag) than to need an implementation and not have it. Though I don't have much practical experience and could be wrong.